# PrimeFaces sheet: frozen columns

Tags: primefaces

I want to add frozen columns in the PrimeFaces sheet component.
Does anyone know how to do that (or is it possible at all)?

I found one question regarding the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246750/add-frozen-columns-to-a-table

But no one has answered that question.

I am using JSF2.0 and PrimeFaces3.1.1

Comment: what do you mean by frozen columns? you got a horizontal scroll?

Comment: Yes. For example, if I have 100 columns and while scrolling horizontally, I need first three columns to be appeared always. So, in this case these three columns are frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. See topic in PrimeFaces forum: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14037&p=42411&hilit=frozen#p42336

Comment: ok. thanks for the info. I searched a little bit and found that RichFaces provides this feature: http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&skin=wine